# How can I calculate business hours between two dates? with working time 9Am to 5 Pm

Tags: formula

How can I calculate business hours between two dates? For example, we have two dates; 01/01/2010 15:00 and 04/01/2010 12:00 And we have working hours 09:00 to 17:00 in weekdays How can I calculate working hours in Salesforce formula field

Comment: Have you tried the example on the [Sample Date Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm) page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a formula field.

You can do it with Apex (and a trigger) to calculate the business hours between two fields based on a Business Hours record.

The example on the formulas page won't be much help, as it's not dynamic to account for holidays like are available when using the Business Hours object.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicated formula, write a class like below and call `getBusinessHourTimeDifference` with correct parameters.

```
public with sharing class BusinessHoursServices
{
    @testVisible static BusinessHours defaultBH
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultBH == null)
                defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            return defaultBH;
        }
        private set;
    }

    /**
    * getBusinessHourTimeDifference
    * returns business hours difference in milliseconds based on two datetime. 
    * @param businessHoursId - BusinessHour Id
    * @param startDate - start date time
    * @param endDate - end date time
    * @return Long
    */
    public static Long getBusinessHourTimeDifference(Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
    {
        return BusinessHours.diff(defaultBH.Id, startDate, endDate);
    }
 }
```